# how do i get a mesh to change when using setHovered() , trying to get them to change individuly

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I've got a multi mesh .gltf model loaded and running in react, and i just got the animation going with clicked on off options. I'm  noobish when it comes to advanced react.My issue is i want the individuate meshes to change colour when hovered over . I've try ed a few approaches and the following code is as close as I have gotten, but when hovering over one i get All. looking for a nudge in the right direction, learning as i go.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useGLTF, useAnimations, useCursor } from '@react-three/drei';

export default function Model(props) {
    const group = useRef();
    const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF('/v3.gltf');
    const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    useCursor(hovered);
    const colored = hovered ? 0xffb6ff : 0xff00ff;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (clicked) {
            actions.Animation.stop();
        } else {
            actions.Animation.play();
        }
    });
    return (
        <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
            <group name='Scene'>
                <group name='Armature' scale={[6.5, 6.5, 6.5]}>
                    <primitive object={nodes.centerBone} />
                    <primitive object={nodes.centerBone001} />
                    <primitive object={nodes.IK} />
                    <primitive object={nodes.IKK} />
                    <skinnedMesh
                        name='Whale'
                        geometry={nodes.Whale.geometry}
                        material={materials.pinkwhale}
                        skeleton={nodes.Whale.skeleton}
                    />
                </group>

                <mesh
                    name='react'
                    castShadow
                    receiveShadow
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onClick={(e) => (e.stopPropagation(), setClicked(!clicked))}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onPointerOver={(e) => (
                        e.stopPropagation(), setHovered(true)
                    )}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onPointerOut={(e) => (
                        e.stopPropagation(), setHovered(false)
                    )}
                    geometry={nodes.react.geometry}
                    material={nodes.react.material}
                    position={[0, 6.25, 6.77]}
                    scale={[2.56, 0.87, 0.87]}
                >
                    <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' color={colored} />
                </mesh>

                <mesh
                    name='react01'
                    castShadow
                    receiveShadow
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onClick={(e) => (e.stopPropagation(), setClicked(!clicked))}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onPointerOver={(e) => (
                        e.stopPropagation(), setHovered(true)
                    )}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    onPointerOut={(e) => (
                        e.stopPropagation(), setHovered(false)
                    )}
                    geometry={nodes.react01.geometry}
                    material={nodes.react01.material}
                    position={[0, 4.5, 7.7]}
                    scale={[2.56, 0.87, 0.87]}
                >
                    <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' color={colored} />
                </mesh>
```

Comment: You might just need multiple setHovered states instead of just one so that you know which part was hovered.

Comment: I'll give that a try, I'm also looking at using just the onPointerOver & Out to pass a ref or name of the mesh to  func or useEffect then pass back to the sending mesh. I'm finding funny things with three.js fiber when working on a model component for <canvas>